# Deleting a character within a string an replacing with a different character from a list that includes the original character

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

def replace_base_randomly_using_names(base_seq):
    """Return a sequence with the base at a randomly selected position of base_seq
    replaced by a base chosen randomly from the three bases that are not at that
    position."""
    position = randint(0, len(base_seq) - 1) # −1 because len is one past end
    base = base_seq[position]
    bases = 'TCAG'
    bases.replace(base, '') # replace with empty string!
    newbase = bases[randint(0,2)]
    beginning = base_seq[0:position] # up to position
    end = base_seq[position+1:] # omitting the base at position
    return beginning + newbase + end
```

This is supposed to simulate a mutation. I don't understand how a different base (from within TCAG) is chosen so as to ensure the base is indeed changed, as the doctype mentions.

Edit:

Another version of the above code that does the same thing:

```
def replace_base_randomly(base_seq):
    position = randint(0, len(base_seq) - 1)
    bases = 'TCAG'.replace(base_seq[position], '')
    return (base_seq[0:position] +
            bases [randint(0,2)] +
            base_seq[position+1:])
```

To be clear, my question is how is the base being replaced with a different base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider interleaving print statements into the code and you can see what it's doing. Here's the algorithm:

- Choose a random index in the string. Save it as "position."
- Save the character at that index as "base".
- In the list 'TCAG', replace the character "base" with an empty string, and save that list as "bases" (so it will contain every base that wasn't the one at the index "position").
- Choose a random character from "bases" and save that character as "newbase". (So it'll be one of the three bases remaining after removing the base you originally picked at random.)
- Return the concatenation of three strings: the original string up to but not including "position", "newbase", and the original string following but not including "newbase."

It doesn't edit the string -- it creates a new string from the two pieces of the old string, plus the new base, and returns that.

Comment: This did it for me. Your third point made it click. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in python, you should re-assign the string returned from `bases.replace(base, '')` to `bases`.

```
bases = bases.replace(base, '')
```

Comment: I'm not following...the code works; I just don't know how. Specifically, see the `newbase` line. Assume we have a sequence of ATTGC. Position 3 (G) is selected to be replaced. How is the code ensuring that position 3 become A, T, or C?

Answer (score 0):

The line `bases.replace(base, '')` doesn't actually change the `bases` string. To change the `bases` string, you must set `bases = bases.replace(base, '')`. Test it yourself

```
bases = 'ACGT'
base = 'A'
print bases #prints 'ACGT'
bases.replace(base, '')
print bases #prints 'ACGT'
bases = bases.replace(base, '')
print bases #prints 'CGT'
```

From here, now that the list of possible bases has been reduced to only bases that are mutations, the function randomly chooses one base with `bases[randint(0, 2)]` and appends it to the new sequence.

Comment: But my code above does work; it replaces a random base every time with  one of the three other bases.

Comment: It works for replacing `G`s, because `newbase = bases[randint(0,2)]` is only selecting a random base from `bases[0:3] = 'TCA'`. If you try your code on another position where the base is `T`. I guarantee that if you run it 100 times trying to replace a `T`, it will sometimes replace `T` with `T`.

Comment: That's not true. I've ran it a few times; each time a random base is replaced with a different base (other than itself, i.e. A is not replaced with A). Try it: `replace_base_randomly_using_names('ATTGCCGTTAATGCCGTA')`